# Logging unnecessary lines on running the code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help with my nodejs code

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function processFile(filePath) {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
  const lines = content.split('\n');

  const wordIdMaps = lines.map(() => ({ wordIdMap: {}, currentId: 1 }));

  lines.forEach((line, index) => {
    const words = line.split(' ');
    const wordIdMap = wordIdMaps[index].wordIdMap;
    let currentId = wordIdMaps[index].currentId;

    words.forEach((word) => {
      if (!wordIdMap[word]) {
        wordIdMap[word] = currentId;
        currentId++;
      }
    });
  });

  return { lines, wordIdMaps }; // Return both lines and wordIdMaps
}

function customConsoleLog(logFormat, wordIdMaps) {
  const lines = wordIdMaps.map((map) => Object.entries(map.wordIdMap).map(([word, id]) => `${word}:${id}`).join(' '));

  lines.forEach((line, index) => {
    const wordIdMap = wordIdMaps[index].wordIdMap;

    const replacedLog = logFormat.replace(/\${(\d+)}/g, (_, id) => {
      const word = Object.keys(wordIdMap).find((key) => wordIdMap[key] == id);
      return word !== undefined ? word : '${' + id + '}';
    });

    const words = line.split(' ');
    const replacedLine = replacedLog.replace(/\${\d+}/g, (match) => {
      const id = match.slice(2, -1);
      return words[id - 1] !== undefined ? words[id - 1] : match;
    });

    console.log(replacedLine);
  });
}

// Command-line arguments
const filePath = process.argv[2];
const logFormat = process.argv[3];

if (!filePath || !logFormat) {
  console.log('Please provide both a file path and a custom console log format as command-line arguments.');
} else {
  const { lines, wordIdMaps } = processFile(filePath);

  customConsoleLog(logFormat, wordIdMaps);
}
```

This nodejs code takes data from a txt file and provides custom output through command line argument
If I write:

```
node index.js test.txt '${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}'
```

The code splits the file content's lines and then splits the words by whitespace, and provides the output in which it reads and lists first four words of every line of the file content, for example:

```
apple boy cat dog
elephant fish god hen
```

But the output creates an extra line of IDs after listing out all the lines

```
apple boy cat dog
elephant fish god hen
 ${2} ${3} ${4}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I surmise the extra id's have been printed because the file have either empty lines or lines with only whitespaces. Can you double check the content of the file once to see if it has empty lines at the end? If this is the case just add one base case inside your `forEach` loop: `lines.forEach((line, index)) => {if(line.trim() === '')return; //... rest}`

Comment: @mandy8055 no, my txt file doesn't contain any empty line, I guess the code checks for every line also the first word of one extra line which doesn't even exist

Answer (score 0):

As @mandy8055 has already pointed out, it may has to do with an additional empty line including a line break (CR or CRLF or LF).

I can reproduce your image of error if i add an extra empty line.

Try debug read the length of the variable **lines** inside your  function **processFile** - it adds one extra entry!

To make your code more rubust about this, additional fixes would be:

1. On line 5: filter out empty lines

exchange:

```js
const lines = content.split('\n');
```

with:

```js
const lines = content.split('\n').filter((line)=>{return line 
!= ""});
```

2. or even one step earlier:
   use .trim() on line 4:

```js
const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line is doing it:

```js
return word !== undefined ? word : '${' + id + '}';
```

Try this instead:

```js
return (word !== undefined) ? word : '';
```

Not exactly the best error handling, but it suppresses those extraneous tags.